# How to have two cron jobs in the same project in jenkins

Tags: php, jenkins, cron, phpunit

I have a jenkins job executing two different tasks, say running phpunit tests and generating code coverage report. My requirement is that while my phpunit tests and code coverage should run every hour (H * * * *), the mail sending schedule for both of them should be different. For phpunit, the mail should be sent everyhour (right after the test execution), for code coverage, mail should be sent only "once" in a day (preferably morning). I've scheduled the first at H * * * * but how do I schedule the other one. I believe, I can give only one cron job in Jenkins. Both of them are in same jenkins project.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cron job so that the Jenkins job is called every hour like you did, and every time it runs it sends the phpunit mail. Then as part of the job, check (using your favorite programming language) that the hour is equal to, say, 3 (if you were running it at 3 AM) and if so, send the code coverage mail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The jenkins job is scheduled using the UI which jenkins provides. I did not have to write a separate cron calling the jenkins job. Under this scenario, things are getting a little complicated. The said cron is in-built in jenkins.